# Why does blowing air through pursed lips make the air cooler than if we exhale through wide open mouth?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, turbulence

When we try to cool something through blowing on it, we purse our lips to exhale air through a narrow opening, which produces cooler air. However, if we open our mouths wide and exhale , then the air is hotter. What is happening here ?
Why does changing the area through which we blow, change the temperature of the air we exhale ?